# Structure nested list of objects for searching by object key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data acquired from collection points (`sourceId`), which record data (`samples`) from different probes (`probeId`). I need to structure the data as `samples` by `probeId` by `sourceId`.

### Specification

1. Insert often
2. Read occasionally
3. Never update or delete
4. Read by indexing with a list of `sourceIds` and a list of `probeIds`
5. Insert atomically, including when `probeId` is not in the list of probes and the probe sub-document needs to be created

### Question

What is the best structure to achieve the above? Particularly, how can the preferred structure facilitate achieving point 5? I have not been able to get upsert to match only for `probeId` and ignore `samples` and `meta`.

So far I have considered the following 2 structures:

```json
{'sourceId': ObjectId(),
  'probes': [
    {
      'probeId': ObjectId(),
      'meta': {...},
      'samples': [...]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and

```json
{'sourceId': ObjectId(),
  'probes': [
    {
      ObjectId(): {                # probeId key
        'meta': {...},
        'samples': [...]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I use the first structure and search like this:

```json
  db.collection.aggregate(
    {'$match': {'sourceId': {'$in': source_id_list}}},
    {'$project': {'probes': {'$filter': {'input': '$probes', 'cond': {'$in': ['$$this.probeId', probe_id_list]}}}}}
  )
```

For clarity point 5 should work as follows (assuming using the first structure):

Before inserting:

```json
{'sourceId': ObjectId('1'),
  'probes': [
    {
      'probeId': ObjectId('2'),
      'meta': {...},
      'samples': [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

After inserting a sample for `probeId`=3 for `sourceId`=1 (note that not only has the sample been added but also the containing subdocument):

```json
{'sourceId': ObjectId('1'),
  'probes': [
    {
      'probeId': ObjectId('2'),
      'meta': {...},
      'samples': [...]
    },
    {
      'probeId': ObjectId('3'),
      'meta': {},
      'samples': [<NEW SAMPLE DATA>]
    }
  ]
}
```